# Magento - Indexer model is not defined

Tags: search, magento-1.8, indexer

After installing the **Activo Advanced Search Extension for Magento** we get this error:

Indexer model is not defined.

Trace:

```
#0 httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(309): Mage::throwException('Indexer model i...')

#1 httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Block/Adminhtml/Notifications.php(41): Mage_Index_Model_Process->getIndexer()

#2 httpdocs/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/index/notifications.phtml(27): Mage_Index_Block_Adminhtml_Notifications->getProcessesForReindex()

#3 httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/vhosts...')

#4 httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')

#5 httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()

#6 httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()

#7 httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Block/Adminhtml/Notifications.php(67): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()

#8 httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Index_Block_Adminhtml_Notifications->_toHtml()

#9 httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()

#10 httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()

#11 httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()

#12 httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('notifications', true)

#13 httpdocs/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page.phtml(55): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('notifications')

#14 httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/vhosts...')

#15 httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')

#16 httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()

#17 httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()

#18 httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()

#19 httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()

#20 httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()

#21 httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/DashboardController.php(43): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()

#22 httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_DashboardController->indexAction()

#23 httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')

#24 httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))

#25 httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()

#26 httpdocs/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)

#27 httpdocs/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')

#28 {main}

Error log record number: 597672822834
```

I've tried disabling APC, Memcached and Varnish but this doesn't make a difference. Also checked the permissions but everything appears to be installing correctly.

Also tried the install via Magento Connect and done a manual install but still no joy.

Any idea's on this?
Cheers
Steve

Answer (score 1):

Open the page:

includes\src\Mage_Index_Model_Process.php

In the function “public function getIndexer()”, find the below line:

```
Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('index')->__('Indexer model is not defined.'));
```

Add add this debug line, just before the line:

```
echo $code;exit;
```

and try to access the index page again. This should show you the module or reason which  is creating problems.  Look specially in the extensions that you recently installe (Activo Advanced Search Extension for Magento )